# QGIS Marker orientation/rotation does not transfer on Webmap

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis2web

I have a shapefile that contains a column of orientation. I use that column to assign the orientation of the marker.
[image: Markers Rotated]

My problem is that when I transfer the file into a leaflet webmap, I get an error regarding the orientation:

```
"line 217, in getSymbolAsStyle
              if symbol.dataDefinedAngle().useExpression():
             AttributeError: 'QgsProperty' object has no attribute 'useExpression'"
```

Is there a workaround I could do?

Comment: Hi Pavlos Zoulis, welcome to GIS SE. I guess you should describe a bit more in detail **how** you export your map to leaflet. Otherwise, it is difficult to help.

Comment: Do you use svg marker?

Comment: @Babel I use the plug-in of qgis2web.

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz Yeah I use a svg marker. But if I try to use the plug-in with the rotated svgs I receive an error. If I try to create a leaflet with no rotation the plug-in is successful.

Comment: I'm not sure if the plugin is able to translate the rotation from QGIS to leaflet. There is no 1:1 translation, some special features must be adapted in the leaflet code manually. Not sure if this is the case here, but I suppose so.

Comment: @Babel thanks for the response, I am afraid that the manual change of the HTML code will affect the rotation of all the markers at the same time, I am not sure I can access that property of each marker individually through the HTML code. But I might be wrong about this, that is what I am trying to check in here.

Comment: So probably you should ask two different questions: 1) is the plugin able to export the rotation? (my guess: no, but I'm not sure) and 2) how to change the code in the way you want. I can't help you with this.

Comment: It is a bug in the plugin source code. It uses functions (`useExpression` and `expressionOrField`) removed from PyQGIS 3.

Comment: this is the question/answer that led to qgis2web having that code https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/211361/qgis-retrieve-field-used-in-data-defined-override

Comment: @andreaordonselli I was able to find a solution by modifying the html code. Probably I could try and update the python plug in but I am ok with the html solution as well.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix this error by using a svg marker with no rotation and adding the marker rotation in the html file. My rotation is saved under a column named Azimuth. The necessary Additions are placed in comments inside the code:

```
    function style_photos_1_0(rotationAngle) {
        return {
            pane: 'pane_photos_1',
    rotationAngle: rotationAngle, <!-- And here -->
    rotationOrigin: 'center center',
    icon: L.icon({
        iconUrl: 'markers/reshot-icon-arrow-down-Y8N3B2ASPG.svg',
        iconSize: [15.2, 15.2]
    }),
            interactive: true,
        }
    }
    map.createPane('pane_photos_1');
    map.getPane('pane_photos_1').style.zIndex = 401;
    map.getPane('pane_photos_1').style['mix-blend-mode'] = 'normal';
    var i =0;
    var layer_photos_1 = new L.geoJson(json_photos_1, {
        attribution: '',
        interactive: true,
        dataVar: 'json_photos_1',
        layerName: 'layer_photos_1',
        pane: 'pane_photos_1',
        onEachFeature: pop_photos_1,
        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
            var context = {
                feature: feature,
                variables: {}
            };
    
            return L.marker(latlng, style_photos_1_0(feature.properties['Azimuth']  ));<!-- Add feature.properties['Azimuth'] where each marker rotation is saved! -->
        },
    });
```

Comment: Bolding doesn't work in a code block. Use comments instead.